# code wrong haskell  Couldn't match expected type `[(Key, Value)]'

Tags: haskell

what is wrong with this piece of code, its in a case statement

```
loop :: Table -> IO ()
loop table = do 
        putStr "Command: " 
        x <- getLine
        case x of
              "add" -> do putStr "Key: "; y <- getLine; putStr "Value: ";  z <- getLine; add y z table; loop table    

add :: Key -> Value -> Table -> Table
add key v table  | table == empty   = [(key, v)]
                 | otherwise        = ((key, v) : remove key table)

type Table = [(Key,Value)]
type Key = String
type Value = String
remove :: Key -> Table -> Table
remove key ((a, b) :table) 
        | key ==a                   = table
        | ((a, b) :table) == empty  = empty
        | otherwise                 = ((a, b) : remove key table)
```

Comment: Which line gives you the error message? Is that the full error message? What are `Key`, `Table` and `Value` defined as?

Comment: To test for empty list, it's more common to use `null :: [a] -> Bool` predicate or pattern match against `[]` directly. Please show your definition for `remove` too.

Answer (score 6):

Here's your function again (reformatted a bit):

```
loop table = do 
        putStr "Command: " 
        x <- getLine
        case x of "add" -> do 
            putStr "Key: " 
            y <- getLine
            putStr "Value: "
            z <- getLine
            add y z table
            loop table
```

The problem is that `add y z table` isn't an IO action like the `putStr`s before. You seem to think that the call to `add` actually modifies the table, which it doesn't!

As for fixing it: try assigning the result of `add` to something in a `let` clause. I'm not going to spell it out, since this look like homework.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that `value y table` should be `putStrLn (value y table)`.

As things stand, you are looking up the value but not doing anything with the answer you get back.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have

```
type Key = String
```

somewhere, your value function is quite obscure here:

```
| lookup key ((a,b) : table) == Just b  = b
```

This surely could be simplified to

```
| key == a = b
```

Answer (score 0):

You also have some lingering bugs in `remove`

```
remove :: Key -> Table -> Table
remove key ((a, b) : etable)
  | key == a = table
  | ((a, b) : table) == empty = empty
  | otherwise = ((a, b) : remove key table)
```

Ask yourself what should be tested for `empty`? What happens if `a` doesn't appear in `table`?